# Intrument lib jars inside web application using ant

Tags: java, ant, cobertura

I have a web application. I want to instrument com.mycompany*jar inside XX.war/WEB-INF/lib.
I have to do this with ant cobertura tasks.

Is it possible to instrument classes in selected jars inside war file with ant task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your jars contain classes that are all in the same package(s), you can use the form with "<includeClasses regex=..." (note: try regular glob patterns before you try regex, in my experience).

You can pass a war file, and it will instrument the classes from the pattern in any jar within WEB-INF/lib (or classes within WEB-INF/classes).

```
  <cob:cobertura-instrument datafile="${todir}/${instrument.ser.filename}" >
    <includeClasses regex="com.mycompany.*" />

    <instrumentationClasspath>
      <pathelement path="${war.file}"/>
    </instrumentationClasspath>
  </cob:cobertura-instrument>
```

Alternatively, if you really need to pinpoint specific jars within WEB-INF/lib/ folder, you can try the form with ant zip/jar filesets (I haven't tried it):

```
  <cob:cobertura-instrument datafile="${todir}/${instrument.ser.filename}" >
     <zipfileset src="${war.file}" includes="WEB-INF/lib/com.mycompany*.jar"/>
  </cob:cobertura-instrument>
```

If all else fails, I would do what you probalby have considered: extract these jars, instrument them (with the first form) and re-package them.